# Multiple Joi validation types

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I search a lot but nothing found to allow multiple type validation in `Joi`

Link: https://github.com/hapijs/joi

I would like to use something like this:

```
validate: {
    type: joi.or([
        joi.string(),
        joi.array(),
    ])
};
```

Comment: Did [my post below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468779/multiple-joi-validation-types/41468932#41468932) answer your question? If so then you can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157646) so that other people see that it's answered when they search for this topic.

Answer (score 30):

Try:

```
validate: {
    type: joi.alternatives().try(joi.string(), joi.array())
}
```

or:

```
validate: {
    type: [joi.string(), joi.array()]
}
```

See: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.1.0/API.md#alternatives

Answer (score 1):

```js
export const saveDeviceCommandsSchema = {
  devices: [
    Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()).required(),
    Joi.string().valid('all').required().lowercase()
  ],
  info: Joi.array()
};
```

example specifying more than a validation rule to an object